# How to fetch value of a drop-down and a text box after btn click?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form wherein I have a drop down which is being populated from the database also I have an input box right beneath it. I want to `fetch the value of both the fields via Ajax using jQuery and insert them into the database`.

#### Problem: Value of the text field is getting inserted successfully but the value of drop down is not getting inserted.

I know I will have to fetch the value of the drop down separately and then add it to the data in ajax but I am not able to figure how to do the same.

## NOTE: COULD THE DOWN VOTERS BE KIND ENOUGH TO TELL ME WHY I WAS DOWNVOTED SO THAT I COULD IMPROVE UPON THINGS.

`sub_category_add.php`

```
<form method="post">

          <select id="cat_sub_cat">     

          <?php
          $data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM category");
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
          {
              echo "<option value=".$row['cid'].">".$row['category']."</option>";  
          }

          ?>      

          </select><br><br>     

          <h3>Add Sub Categories</h3><br>    

          <input type="text" name="sub_cat"><br><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert" id="sub_cat_btn"> 
 </form>
```

`Ajax File:`

```
$(document).on('click','#sub_cat_btn', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:"sub_cat_add_back.php",
        method:"post",
        data:$('form').serialize(),
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(strMsg){
            $("#cat_sub_msg").html(strMsg);

            }

        })
```

`sub_cat_add_back.php`

```
<?php

include "../includes/config.php";


$name=$_POST['sub_cat'];
$cid=$_POST['cat_sub_cat'];


$data=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO subcategory (name,cid) VALUES ('$name','$cid')");
if($data=="true")
{
    echo "Successfully Inserted";   
}
else
{
    echo "Error";   
}


?>
```

Comment: your select has no name attribute. *For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute.* - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: You need the add the name for Select box  <select id="cat_sub_cat" name ="cat_sub_cat">

Comment: @billyonecan Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @Siva Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get values on click instead of form serialize. add id in `input`

```
 <input type="text" name="sub_cat" id="custom">

    $("#cat_sub_cat option:selected");
    $("#custom").val();
```

and if you want to do that with form serialize then add name in your `select`

`<select id="cat_sub_cat" name="your_select_name">`

Comment: Glad to know it help you.

Comment: I upvoted you and also marked your answer but looks like someone else downvoted you.

Comment: No problem man for down vote, whoever done this and Thanks for accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the select tag does not have the Name attribute

```
 <select id="cat_sub_cat" name="cat_sub_cat">
```